# Microsoft Access - Case Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've just try using MS Access 2007
now I want to update a column based on other column value, in MY SQL it was successfull running this query

```
UPDATE HAI
SET REGION=(
CASE
  WHEN (NUMREG LIKE '%1') THEN 'BDG'
  WHEN (NUMREG LIKE '%2') THEN 'JKT'
  WHEN (NUMREG LIKE '%3') THEN 'KNG'
END);
```

This query won't run in MS Access, there is error `Sytax error (missing operator) in query expression`. How can I solve this?

Comment: What if you remove parentheses?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no CASE ... WHEN in Access SQL.  You can use the [Switch Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) instead.

```
UPDATE HAI
SET REGION = Switch(
    NUMREG Like '*1', 'BDG',
    NUMREG Like '*2', 'JKT',
    NUMREG Like '*3', 'KNG'
    );
```

That query uses Access' default (ANSI 89 mode) * instead of % wildcard character.  If you want to use the % wildcard, you can do it with the ALike comparison operator.

```
UPDATE HAI
SET REGION = Switch(
    NUMREG ALike '%1', 'BDG',
    NUMREG ALike '%2', 'JKT',
    NUMREG ALike '%3', 'KNG'
    );
```

Comment: +1 You can also use the "IIf" function, but Switch will be cleaner in this example.