# What is the correct CASE SELECT Statement in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, case

I am using vb.net and Access 2010 as the database (.accdb)

This works with MySQL:

```
SELECT user_id, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name,
CASE is_enable WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END 
FROM tbl_user_accounts ORDER BY user_id
```

But when passed the same query to Access, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized keyword WHEN.
```

So I assume that the CASE Statement is different in access, or does access has that function at all?

P.S.
is_enable is boolean

Comment: There is no Case ... When. Switch function is an alternative. See **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534425/microsoft-access-case-query.**

Comment: @chuff, how do you do something like CASE ELSE in the Switch function?

Comment: @paynet you can do it on `vba`

Comment: @JW, I haven't tried VBA. :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out:
Access 2010 does not have the CASE function, we use SWITCH instead.

`SELECT user_id, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name,  SWITCH(is_enable=True,'Yes',is_enable=False,'No')
FROM tbl_user_accounts ORDER BY user_id`

Thanks to chuff and JW.

Comment: Be aware that if none of your test conditions evaluate to True, the Switch function will return NULL. If you want to handle a default case where nothing matches, use: Switch(cond1, exp1, cond2, exp2, ..., True, expn). The last condition, True, will always match if none of the others did. So you'll always at least return a default value of expn.

Comment: Thanks @Yawar, I am actually looking for something like the CASE ELSE function to handle results not in the CASE Selection.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, [you can use `IIF`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

```
IIF(is_enable = 1 , 'YES', 'NO')
```

Comment: same result @JW, still getting the Unrecognized WHEN error.

Comment: no, the `IIF` statement

Comment: IIF works like a charm! Thanks JW. But I still need the CASE for future use of comparison with more than 2 values.

Comment: i have no access installed on my machine but i guess, `access` doens't support `cASE` statement. i can't find either on the docs.

Comment: @paynet *"In Microsoft Access, the `Case statement can only be used in VBA code`."* [see here: MS Access (Case Statement)](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php)

Comment: paynet, I've used IIF extensively as a workaround, both nested and with compound conditions, a la, IIF((field1 = "Y" or field2 = "Y) and field3 > 100, 1.75*field5, IIF(.... etc. For complex conditions. SWITCH I've always found a bit confusing to work with. As JW cites, CASE is available in VBA, but I've never had a need to work with it.

Comment: You will be a long tome looking for a boolean equal to 1 in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou, I figured that one out, MS Access returns either true or false for a boolean type field.

Comment: Ms Access returns either **-1** or 0 for a true or false.

Comment: At first, I tried checking for 1 or 0 for true and false respectively but it always returns false, then I tried using True and False as is (is_enable = True, is_enable = false) which actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Choose is another Access (really VBA) function available in queries, similar to Switch but returns an index to a list of answers. For instance, Choose([Choice], "A","B","C") would return "B" if Choice was 2. I've found it useful in the past.

Comment: I'll keep this handy. Thanks @Peter

Answer (score 1):

This is really a display issue, and would possibly be best done somewhere other than SQL. `is_enabled` is clearly a Boolean/YesNo data type, so you can just format it:

```
 SELECT Format(AYesNo,'Yes/No') As ATextYN FROM table1
```

Or

```
 Format(AYesNo,'True/False')
 Format(AYesNo,'On/Off')
```

All work in VB.Net and return text, not boolean.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Comment: I tested this and it also works. But my purpose for using CASE Statement, which is now SWITCH Statement in Access is to be able to compare more than 2 values and not just boolean alone. It just happens that my example was boolean. On the other hand, just like what chuff said, the SWITCH Statement in Access is proving to be confusing to work with. Nonetheless, thanks for the answer, I didn't know such a function exist. I'll keep this handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourColumnName=case when is_enable=1 then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
```

Comment: same result @polin, still getting the Unrecognized WHEN error.

Comment: you need to give a column name of your table in "yourColumnName".

Comment: Yes I did that. I'm looking into @chuff's answer. Seems like Access does not have the CASE function.

Comment: oh. thats right. I didn't  notice that you are using Access. Its possible in sql server