# Updating a Query with SQL in Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a Query in Microsoft Access using SQL. I am getting the following error when I run "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" I've added the following code to bottom of my basic SELECT/FROM Query script.

```
UPDATE [HRBI Query]
SET [HRBI Query].[PaySegmentMultiplier] = (CASE WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Above top segment' THEN 0 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Below segment 1' THEN 1.35 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S1' THEN 1.25 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S2' THEN 1.15 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S3' THEN .90 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S4' THEN .60 ELSE CASE
WHEN [PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S5' THEN .40 ELSE CASE
ELSE PaySegmentMultiplier
END
END
END
END
END
END) 
FROM [HRBI Query];
```

I am new to SQL. Can anyone explain why I am receiving this error and how to fix? Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried using SWITCH, but am still receiving an error on sytax. Any ideas?

```
SELECT SWITCH([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Above top segment',[HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier = 0,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Below segment 1', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =1.35,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S1', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =1.25,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S2', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =1.15,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S3', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =.90,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S4', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =.60,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S5', [HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier =.40, True,'Error') 
FROM [HRBI Query];
```

EDIT: I tried this and still syntax error?

```
SET [HRBI Query].[PaySegmentMultiplier] = Switch (
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Above top segment', 0, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Below segment 1', 1.35, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S1', 1.25, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S2', 1.15, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S3', .90, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S4', .60, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S5', .40, TRUE, PaySegmentMultiplier);
```

Comment: don't think you need else case... change them to just have 'when'.. but I thought access didn't support case in SQL... perhaps `switch` or `iif`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785586/what-is-the-correct-case-select-statement-in-access-2010

Comment: You have `[HRBI Query].PaySegmentMultiplier = 0` where a value `0` would belong. See the example below.

Comment: Thanks Andre451. I tried Switch but am still getting syntax error? Does it make a difference that I am adding the SET to the bottom of the main Query code. (SELECT/FROM)?

Comment: SET doesn't go together with SELECT FROM. SET is for UPDATE queries. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, the best translation of `CASE/WHEN` would be the nested [IIF()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) function. Also in update SQL statements with Access' dialect, you would not use the `FROM` clause at end.

The only challenge is keeping track of parentheses which should equal the number of IIFs. I indent below to help visualize:

```
UPDATE [HRBI Query]
SET [HRBI Query].[PaySegmentMultiplier] = 
IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Above top segment', 0,
   IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Below segment 1', 1.35,
      IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S1', 1.25,
        IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S2', 1.15,
           IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S3', .90, 
              IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S4', .60, 
                 IIF([PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S5', .40, 
                     PaySegmentMultiplier
                 )
              )
           )
        )
     )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN .. ELSE .. END` is for Sql Server.

In Access you use the [Switch](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) function:

```
Switch ( expression1, value1, expression2, value2, ... expression_n, value_n )
```

so in your case

```
UPDATE [HRBI Query]
SET [HRBI Query].[PaySegmentMultiplier] = Switch (
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'France'  AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Above top segment', 0, 
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'Below segment 1', 1.35,
[PayGroupCountryDesc] = 'Country' AND BasePayRangeSegment = 'S1', 1.25
[...etc...]
[and to simulate ELSE]
True, PaySegmentMultiplier
)
```

or for a SELECT query:

```
SELECT Switch ( ... ) AS NewPaySegmentMultiplier FROM [HRBI Query]
```