# MsAccess - How to update a column conditionally with different values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database in that a need to set different values in a column dependent upon values in a second column. 
I wish to do this (descibed in not working code but I think you'll understand):

UPDATE new
(SET Domain = 'INFO'
WHERE new.node = 'ABC' or new.node = 'DEF')
or 
(SET Domain = 'FOO'
WHERE new.node = 'GHI' or new.node = 'JKL')

but I can't figure out how. Can someone help me?

Regards // PS

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) statement.

```
UPDATE [new]
SET [Domain] = Switch(
    [new].node = 'ABC' OR [new].node = 'DEF', 'INFO',
    [new].node = 'GHI' OR [new].node = 'JKL', 'FOO',
    );
```

Related link: [Microsoft Access - Case Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534425/microsoft-access-case-query)