# Update query with backup option

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create an update that will add "xxx" to the beginning of a Product Number, which is found in

```
table.ProductNo
```

Every now and then, there might already be a code that has had xxx added to the beginning though (because sometimes product numbers get recycled- bad system I know, but it's how things go).

How can I create a query that will just add "xx" to the beginning if "xxx[table.productNo]" already exists?

The statement I'm currently using is

```
UPDATE table SET 
    table.ProductNo = "xxx" & [table.productNo], 
    table.Description = "xxx" & [table.Description], 
    table.OnInternet = 0, 
    table.OnInternetfs = 0, 
    table.OnFlyer = 0, 
    table.OnFSFlyer = 0
WHERE (((table.ProductNo)=[Enter Product#]));
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I have edited the question to include my current query. The problem is already mentioned. xxx[table.ProductNo] can't exist twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add *xxx* to the start of `ProductNo` unless it already starts with *xxx*.  In that case you want to add *xx* instead.

If that is correct, you can use an `IIf` expression to decide whether to add 2 or 3 *x* characters.

```sql
UPDATE table AS t
SET
    t.ProductNo = IIf(Left(t.ProductNo, 3) = 'xxx', 'xx', 'xxx')
        & [t.productNo],
    t.Description = "xxx" & [t.Description],
    t.OnInternet = 0,
    t.OnInternetfs = 0,
    t.OnFlyer = 0,
    t.OnFSFlyer = 0
WHERE (((t.ProductNo)=[Enter Product#]));
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the second 'xxx'? in line 3?

Comment: `IIf(condition, truepart, falsepart)` So I think you're asking about the falsepart.  That means when the first 3 characters of `ProductNo` are not *'xxx'*, return *'xxx'*.  Then whatever is returned from the `IIf` expression is added to the beginning of `ProductNo`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `CASE` statement to get this working.

```
UPDATE t
SET productNo = CASE WHEN productNo LIKE 'xxx%' THEN 'xx' + productNo ELSE 'xxx' + productNo END
FROM table t
```

**Update**

Access `SWITCH` statement included:

```
UPDATE table
SET product_id = SWITCH(
    productNo LIKE 'xxx*', 'xx' + productNo,
    TRUE, 'xxx' + productNo --Default
    )
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. This is in Access. I don't believe CASE statements work. Unless I've read wrong?

Comment: I believe you can use a SWITCH statement instead. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534425/microsoft-access-case-query