# Update Access database (multiple rows)

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am totally newbie to Access, I used to use Excel to handle my needs for a while.

But by now Excel has become too slow to handle such a big set of data, so I decided to migrate to Access.

Here is my problem

My columns are:

```
Number  | Link                          | Name      | Status
1899    | htto://example.com/code1      | code1     | Done
2       | htto://example.com/code23455  | code23455 | Done
3       | htto://example.com/code2343   | code2343  | Done
13500   | htto://example.com/code234cv  | code234cv | Deleted
220     | htto://example.com/code234cv  | code234cv | Null
400     | htto://example.com/code234cv  | code234cv | Null
```

So I want a way to update `Status` of my rows according to numbers list.

For example I want to update `Status` column for multiple numbers to become `Done`

Simply I want to update "Null status" to become "Done" according to this number list

```
13544
17
13546
12
13548
13549
16000
13551
13552
13553
13554
13555
12500
13557
13558
13559
13560
30
13562
13563
```

Something like this

I tried "update query" but I don't know how to use criteria to solve this problem

In Excel I did that by "conditional formatting duplicates" -with my number list which I wanted to update-

Then "sort by highlighted color" then "fill copy" the status with the value

I know that Access is different but I hope that there is a way to do this task as Excel did.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a book. No amount of handholding (which is not what SO is for) will help you. Try this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Access-2010-Missing-Matthew-MacDonald-ebook/dp/B0043M4Z7A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1389086621&sr=8-1&keywords=ms+access - it looks reasonable. Be warned though, I haven't got a copy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, You can try

```
Update TblA
Set TblA.Status="Done"
where Number in (13544,17,13546,....)
```

Or alternatively easy method is to pull these numbers in IN clause into its own table and use it like this

```
Update TblA 
Set TblA.Status="Done" where Number in (select NumCol from NumTable )
```

or this solution may help you [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534425/microsoft-access-case-query)